# Python Subprocesso conferindo sempre que um novo arquivo é adicionado

Tags: python-3.x, ftp, cpu

**Necessidade:**

Preciso "observar" um diretório, a cada novo arquivo inserido neste diretório preciso fazer uma cópia deste arquivo e encaminhar para um servidor FTP.

**O que tenho:**

Consigo fazer o envio do arquivo por FTP, e consigo conferir os arquivos no diretório.

**O que preciso:**

Preciso de algo Semelhante ao dropbox, um serviço "observando" a pasta e dispare uma ação sempre que um novo arquivo for criado, de preferência em tempo real com apenas o delay de envio por FTP.

Não sei se tem relevância mas precisarei deixar este serviço rodando em máquinas com windows 10, 8 e 7.

Existe alguma forma de fazer isso em **Python**?

**Minha tentativa de solução:**

Pensei em visualizar o diretório e resgatar uma lista dos arquivos lá existentes, então iniciaria um loop ifinito conferindo se a quantidade de arquivos atualmente seria igual ao da primeira contagem, se a ultima contagem der um valor maior que o da contagem anterior é substituido a lista antiga pela atual além de criar uma lista apenas com os itens que não estavam na antiga, com a lista de itens que não estavam na lista antiga realizaria o envio dos arquivos por FTP.

Não sei se ficou claro minha necessidade, tentei colocar o máximo de informação possivel. Espero que possam me ajudar.

Criei este código:

```
from ftplib import FTP
import os, subprocess
import time

f = open("lista.txt", "w")
f.writelines(os.listdir("C:\\Users\\Afonso\\Desktop\\nov2018\\dirteste\\"))
f.close()

def upload(filename, diretorio):
    print("Conectando ao servico FTP")
    ftp = FTP('host')
    print("Logando com Usuário de Senha")
    ftp.login('senha', 'senha')
    print("iniciando debug")
    ftp.set_debuglevel(3)
    print("trocando diretório")
    ftp.cwd('public_html')
    print("Preparando diretorio local e nome de arquivo.")
    file = "C:/Users/Afonso/Desktop/nov2018/dirteste/" + filename
    print("print conferindo se existe diretorio")
    try:
        print("Criando diretorio")
        ftp.mkd('/'+diretorio)
    except:
        pass
    print("enviando arquivo %s" %file)
    diretorio = "/"+diretorio+"/"
    ftp.storbinary("STOR " + diretorio + filename, open(file, 'rb'), 1024)


while True:
    nova_lista = os.listdir("C:\\Users\\Afonso\\Desktop\\nov2018\\dirteste\\")
    lista = open("lista.txt").readlines()
    print(type(lista))
    for file in nova_lista:
        if file not in lista:
            time.sleep(1)
            upload(file, "teste")
    del lista
    del nova_lista
```

O problema é meu medo do processo consumir muito do computador. Haveria uma forma de melhorar ou alguma técnica que não esteja aplicada que melhore o consumo do programa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi colocando um `time.sleep(0.2)` no final do while, processo baixou de 98% para 0% de soncumo da CPU e quando tem muitos arquivos para serem enviados para o servidor varia entre 3% à 0,2% de consumo.